# Any reasons why fread() would be different on a .php file over a .txt file?

Tags: php, fread

Is there any reason why the `fread()` function wouldn't work (no errors show up) when reading from a .php file over a .txt file?

**code**

```
$file = fopen("db.php","rw");
$data = fgets($file, filesize("db.php"));
echo($data);
fclose($file);
die();
```

Comment: `.php` files are plain text files, so there should be no difference.  Have you tried `file_get_contents`? Also, to quote the docs: `Note: If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use file_get_contents() as it has much better performance than the code above.`

Comment: I just tried using that, no luck :(

Comment: @tarnfield, can you post the code?  You never know...

Comment: right click > view html source. I bet your data is there....

Comment: @chris http://cl.ly/H3d ? why this.. only the <?php

Comment: OK WTF? IT WORKS NOW AHH :D:D WOOOOO

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reason why the fread() function wouldn't work (no errors show up) when reading from a .php file over a .txt file?

No, not if you're addressing them the same way (same protocol / method / location). They're all just plain data to `fread()`.

Answer (score 2):

Are the permissions the same for the .php file and the .txt file? I know that seems obvious but sometimes it's the little things that get by us.

Comment: That's interesting. So what exactly happens? When you use fread() to open the PHP file, the stream is empty? But it works for the TXT file?

Comment: Yeah which is why i'm so confused :/

Comment: It works with a .txt file if its not starting with <?php .. ?>

Comment: What about a PHP file that doesn't have <?php .. ?> in it?

Comment: @tarnfeld you're not fetching a file using `http://`, right? Because that would get interpreted if it's a PHP file.

Comment: Ignore my most recent comment, that isnt true, no its just a file in the same directory.

Comment: what you mean, i just put in "db.php" into fopen

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if you want to display that in a page, it will get interpreted, so you should filter its html tags with FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS or some other similar option.